# Socket io channel notification for each user

Tags: node.js, laravel, notifications, redis, socket.io

I am an inexperienced developer, i just started learn node.js socket.io.

I want to make notification for each user if there's post in their wall or someone has replied(commented) to the user's post, just like in the fac*book/go*gle+ notification.

I follow the tutorial here http://www.codesizzle.com/node-js-and-socket-io/

I'm combining it with laravel4 and redis as the handler that publish the message/notif to redis, then nodejs will listen to redis and if there's post/event then send it using socket io to user's browser

Based on my understanding, example:

1. userA posts something to userB
2. userB receive the notif that says "user A has posted something on your wall"

to achieve this:

- I need to make userB subscribes to its own channel, maybe using his id
- then when userA post something, laravel4 will receive the ajax post data
- laravel insert the post to MySQL and publish the user's id + his post to redis
- after that nodejs will receive the event and publish it to userB's browser.

my question is in my statement **"userB subscribes to its own channel, maybe using his id."** this means userB will subscribe to channel maybe `notif-channel-{userId}` -> `notif-channel-967` , if i have thousands of users then i will have thousands of different channel, maybe from `notif-channel-1` until `notif-channel-50000`,

1. will it become a problem?
2. what is the best practice?
3. does the flow already correct?

thankyou

note :sorry for the bad english.

**UPDATE**

After reading some more articles, i think i change the flow to:

1. UserA posts somethingn on UserB's wall
2. Then send ajax post to laravel so i can put the message/post into the db
3. After that emit/push event to socketio thats working on nodejs server to handle the event and push it to userB's channel, tell userB that userA has posted something
4. If success then notify UserA that his posts is successfull

notice that i dont involve redis in the above flow, any feedbacks?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using sockets to do this is a pretty complicated way of doing things.  It's possible, but all you really need to do is add a timed post request from that page (client side) to check for new comments.

All you really need at that point is in the db.  From, To, Date, Message.

With sockets you'd have to set up a channel for each user that has a 'wall', and anyone that is viewing a persons 'wall' will have to subscribe to it, and if it's a lot of people, you will have issues when you need to expand.  That means using redis with sockets.io.

While that's 'cool' to do, it's overkill in my opinion.

Comment: I'm still too new to stackoverflow to edit my answer, so as a reminder....Keep It Simple.

Comment: Also, if you want users to know if they have a new comment on their wall while they are not viewing their own wall, simply check the last time they viewed their wall, if it's less than the newest comments time, then they have a new comment on their wall.

Comment: "but all you really need to do is add a timed post request from that page (client side) to check for new comments." you meant using ajax request e.g: every 10 seconds request to server to check new comment/notif/etc? yea im thinking that way too before i found socket, i'm still thinking the advantages and disadvantages though

Comment: Exactly.  You can always still use sockets later for a live chat or something later, it's not a bad thing to get to know how to use a system.

Comment: actually if i get it pretty clear, for notification/simple message system its better to use timed ajax request right? will it become problem in relatively mid traffic site? i meant, based on the fact, i will have at least 5000 users online, this means if i set the timed ajax to 5 seconds, i will have(assume the timed request starts in the same time) 5000 request every 5seconds, and there will be more users in the future. if i compare with channel, then it will be 5000 channels but i don't know(because i never play with socket) which is better with 5000 channels or 5000 request in every 5 secs

Comment: One way or another, you will have to store new comments in the db, and you will need to access them on a users first visit to a page.  As for timing, do users really need to know the split second (or 5 seconds) a comment is posted?  Not really.  You could have it so a user that is on their own wall will check every 30 seconds, and if they are not viewing their own wall, it will check every minute.

Comment: As for sockets and channels, sorry, I used the wrong term.  Rooms, each user will use their own room, and you can set that up on the fly with sockets.  Again, either way, keeping a socket open per user with thousands of users, or deal with thousands of small post requests.  Sockets will need to use redis if you expand (# of servers or even using cluster), while using post requests means just adding a new server, or cluster, no muss no fuss.

Comment: hmm you got the point, i think ill go with ajax request, maybe 10-30 secs timeout, after reading more about socket articles, i think its better to use socket when bidirectional connections is important and with low latency(e.g: chat system), since client only asking for notification and pushing a simple message then i will use ajax. thanks for your tips sir :D. Anyway bounty needs 20 hours more to be given

Comment: if any one else came here in 2021, long poll, short poll or what ever technique you try, socket io is best in real time web application data handling. Rather then hitting your server for new data frequently, socket io beautifully shares that on the browser as a listener and server have to emit to browser, simple but beautiful

Answer (score 0):

1. Build a microservice which has socket connections using caching  systems and even data warehousing techniques, and at database level use triggers, when data is crud
2. Use parse db server  which has cool feature of subscribing to live query.